# C++ map containing any type of template class object

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, stl, virtual-functions

I am writing a code where we need several kinds of stack. Like `stack<int>, stack<vector<int>>, stack<map<int, string>>, stack<vector<vector<int>>` etc.

I have a base class which contains a virtual function foo(...list of arguments...). This base class is being used as parent for multiple derived classes whose foo() works on different types of stack. So derived1 may be using `stack<int>` while derived2 maybe using `stack<vector<vector<int>>` and so on in their respective foo().

Right now I am passing all the stacks to all the foo functions. So everytime a new stack is to be implemented my foo() definition has to insert one more stack type in base as well as ALL derived classes.

So for example initially I had just one derived class my base and derived classes were like

```
class Base
{
     public:
        void foo(stack<int>) = 0;
} 

class Derived : public Base
{
     public:
        void foo(stack<int>)
        {
            ...
            ...
        }
}
```

Now when a new derived class comes suppose using `stack<vector<int>>`. I would need to update my Base and all derived classes foo() to

```
void foo(stack<int> a, stack<vector<int> b)
{
     ....
     ....
}
```

Instead what I want to achieve now is that I create a `StackWrapper` class which contains all kinds of stack and I can just address different stacks using different keys.

Something like

```
class StackWrapper
{
      stack<int> derived1;
      stack<vector<int>> derived2;
     some-return-type operator[](char ch)
     {
        switch(ch)
        {
            case 'a': return derived1;break;
            case 'b': return derived2;break;
        }
     }
}
```

In this way I would just need to add a new stack type object in this stackwrapper class and then use something like `stackWrapperObj['a']` or `stackWrapperObj['b']` in different derived class' foo().

Is there any method to allow such a class design.

NOTE :- I don't wish to do any casting in foo() like returning `void*` and then casting it later rather I would like to somehow return a casted object somehow depending of the various keys I assign to different stack types. Such that I can do operations like

```
stack<int> a = stackWrapperObject['a'];
stack<vector<int>> b = stackWrapperObject['b'];
```

Comment: Any chance of making the operations you need to do on the various stacks orthogonal to the type contained in the stacks, and use iterators? I.e. approaching the problem generically instead of object-oriented?

Comment: Why are the classes derived from a common type? Is it because you need to switch types at runtime or because you want to be able to reuse the same code when doing different things at compile time?

Comment: Use a template class rather than inheritance.

Comment: @DevSolar I didn't understand your suggestion. Could you please explain a bit.

Comment: Runtime state cannot change the type of variables.  There is going to be many ways to solve your probkem, but the best will depend on why you are using this system to start with.  I could guess at what you really want and solve that, but it would be easier and more likely useful if you explained why you are doing this at all.

Comment: @TilakRajSingh: You use inheritance if you need polymorphism. With C++, quite often you can eschew inheritance and polymorphism by separating storage and logic. Have a look at the standard library's [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) and the [algorithms](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) that can work on these containers, without really "knowing" what it is they contain. The linking element between the two are iterators, which allow algorithms (logic) to operate on any container (storage) providing them.

Comment: @Galik This is because all the derived classes contain the same functions but may work on different types of stack. Its much more complicated than I explained. So it mayb that that derived1 maybe using stacks of type1 and type2 while derived 2 maybe using stacks of type 2, type3, type4 and type5 and so on. Thats why I wish to wrap all the different types of stacks in a single object and put them in a map and address them using just the different keys, or somewhat of that sort

Comment: @Yakk please check the comment just above this

Comment: Would it be possible to write different classes that don't inherit from a common `Base` class (even though that would mean copying the same code over and over)? Or is having a common `Base` class essential and not just a convenience?

Comment: I think the OP might need to read about the Visitor Pattern. It might help them out.

Comment: @tilak that just describes technical details, not what your problem is.  Why have a common base class at all?  It looks, on the surface, like a bad idea.  Possibly you have a reason why it isn't a bad idea, and that reason could tell us how to solve your problem.  Or maybe you think you have that reason, but are wrong.

Comment: @Yakk can we please discuss this here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166525/room-for-tilak-raj-singh-and-yakk

Comment: @Galik having a common base class is essential to the use case...since all the derived classes are stored as pointers to base class for runtime inheritance in a vector for some operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why bother trying to write an `operator[]`?

```
struct StackWrapper
{
    stack<int> a;
    stack<vector<int>> b;
}

void Derived::foo (StackWrapper & stacks)
{
    stack<int> a = stacks.a;
    stack<vector<int>> b = stacks.b;
    // ... 
}
```

At which point you probably don't need those locals, just use `stacks.a` directly

Answer (score 0):

Try using a Visitor Pattern: A basic non template example by using a Caesar Shift:

---

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

#include "CaesarShift.h"

int main() {
    std::string filename;
    std::cout << "Please enter the name of the input file. ";
    std::cin >> filename;

    std::ifstream fileIn;
    std::string   text;

    fileIn.open( filename );
    if ( !fileIn.is_open() ) {
        std::cout << "Failed to open file: " << filename << "." << std::endl;
    }

    fileIn >> text;
    fileIn.close();

    CaesarText caesarText;
    caesarText.addText( text );


    std::cout << "Contents of the Caesar Text before peforming a Caesar Shift:\n"
        << caesarText << std::endl;

    int amount = 0;
    std::cout << "Please enter the amount to shift the text ";
    std::cin >> amount;
    std::cout << "Now performing the Caesar Shift: " << std::endl;

    caesarShift( caesarText, amount );

    std::cout << "Caesar Text after performing a Caesar shift:\n"
        << caesarText << std::endl;

    std::ofstream fileOut;
    fileOut.open( std::string( "shifted_" + filename ) );
    if ( !fileOut.is_open() ) {
        std::cout << "Failed to open shifted_" << filename << std::endl;
    }
    fileOut << caesarText.shiftedText() << std::endl;
    fileOut.close();

    system( "PAUSE" );
    return 0;
}
```

**CaesarShift.h**

```
#ifndef CAESAR_SHIFT_H
#define CAESAR_SHIFT_H

class CaesarText {
    std::string _originalText;
    std::string _shiftedText;

public:
    CaesarText() = default;
    explicit CaesarText( const std::string& text ) :
        _originalText( text ) {}

    void addText( const std::string& text ) {
        _originalText = text;
    }

    std::string originalText() const {
        return _originalText;
    }

    std::string shiftedText() const {
        return _shiftedText;
    }

    friend void caesarShift( CaesarText& c, int amount );

    friend std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& out, const CaesarText& ceasarText );
};

#endif // !CAESAR_SHIFT_H
```

**CaesarShift.cpp**

```
#include "CaesarShift.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& o, const CaesarText& c ) {
    o << "Original Text: " << c._originalText << "\n";
    o << "Shifted Text: " << c._shiftedText << "\n";
    return o;
}

void caesarShift( CaesarText& text, int amount ) {
    // Bound amount to the number of characters in the alphabet
    amount %= 26;

    // Three Different Ways To Perform The Shift //
    /*for ( std::size_t i = 0; i < text._originalText.length(); i++ ) {
        char c = text._originalText[i] + amount;
        text._shiftedText += c;
    }*/

    for ( auto& c : text._originalText ) {
        text._shiftedText += c + amount;
    }

    /*std::transform( text._originalText.begin(), text._originalText.end(),
                std::back_inserter( text._shiftedText ),
                [amount]( unsigned char c ) -> unsigned char { return c + amount; }
    );*/

}
```

**Input: test.txt**

```
Hello
```

**Console & File Output** - Based on user input for how much to shift by:

```
// Shift by 2
Original Text: Hello
Shifted Text: Jgnnq

// Shift by 3
Original Text: Hello
Shifted Text: Khoor

// Shift by 29 (29 % 26) = 3
Original Text: Hello
Shifted Text: Khoor
```

If you look at the class above it only stores two strings. It does have constructors and functions to return the two private members. The implementation to apply the shift to the `CaesarText` is separate from the class or container itself. The same goes for the overloaded operator to easily send this object to the output stream.

In this particular case the function `caeserShift()` takes a reference to a CaesarText and an int. Now this standalone function does the actual `operations or calculations` on the `class object`. The only thing special here is that `caesarShift()` is a friend of `CaesarText` enabling it to access the members directly so that you don't have to have `getters` and create unwanted extra temporaries and copies. So in the end the `algorithm` `caesarShift()` is NOT a member of `CeasarText` but does operations on them. The same pattern is used all through the standard library with containers and iterators.